# Probability of choosing a particular path between $3$ non-collinear cities

Tags: probability, contest-math

> There are $3$ cities $A, B$ and $C$ which are non-collinear. The
> number of ways in which one can go from $A$ to $B$ is $x$. The number
> of ways in which a person can go from $B$ to $C$ is $x^2$ and the
> number of ways in which a person can go from $A$ to $C$ is $x^3$.
> These are the only connected paths. If the total number of ways of
> reaching $C$ from $A$ is $54$, then find the probability that when a
> person goes from $A$ to $C$, he chooses one of the paths on the $B-C$
> trail.

Total number of ways to go from $A$ to $C$ via $B=x \times x^2 = x^3$
Total number of ways to go from $A$ to $C$ directly $=x^3$

Net total number of ways to go from $A$ to $C=x^3+x^3=2x^3$

As per the question $2x^3 = 54 \Rightarrow x = 3$

So shouldn't probability asked in the question be $\frac{27}{54} = \frac{1}{2}$. But upon checking the answer that is given, I am wrong. What am i doing wrong ? Please help !!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: It should be 1/2 only but what's the other answer given? It would be better to include it in your question too..

Comment: @InanimateBeing : The answer has been given as $\frac{1}{10}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is inadequately stated in my opinion. It doesn't specify how the person chooses their path, but expects you to provide a probability. This is the problem.

You are treating the $54$ paths from $A$ to $C$ as equally likely to be chosen. But they are treating the $30$ paths leading away from $A$ as equally likely to be picked. These two assumptions conflict.

By your unjustified assumption, the probability of passing through $B$ is $\frac {27}{54}= \frac 12$. By their unjustified assumption, the probability of passing through $B$ is $\frac 3{30} = \frac 1{10}$.

Since they are the ones who should have made one of the assumptions justifiable, I would award you the win.